# How to get a proper curve fit using Matlab's polyfit?

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, polynomials

I am trying to fit a simple polynomial curve in Matlab. I have measurement data (can be downloaded [here](https://gist.github.com/axelfiedler/ed1f25bd1dbc1da4607217d440afaefb)) that looks plotted like this:

[image: Plot of measurements]

Now I want to fit a polynomial of second degree to this curve. So in Matlab I did the following:

```
load vel.csv
load dp.csv
[p, ~, ~] = polyfit(vel, dp, 2);

figure()
scatter(vel, dp);
hold on;
plot(vel,polyval(p,vel));
hold off;
```

However the result doesn't look like Matlab has fitted the polynomial at all:

[image: Badly fitted curve]

How can I get a decent curve fit using Matlab's `polyfit` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you do not use them, when you specify the additional outputs, `polyfit` is centering and scaling the `x` data before doing the polynomial fit, which results in different polynomial coefficients:

```
>> [p, ~, ~] = polyfit(vel, dp, 2)
p =

    1.4683   35.7426   68.6857

>> p = polyfit(vel, dp, 2)
p =

   0.022630   3.578740  -7.354133
```

This is the relevant extract from the [`polyfit` documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html):

[image]

If you choose that option, you need to use the third output when calling `polyval` to centre and scale your data before applying the polynomial coefficients. My suggestion would be to stick with the second call to `polyfit`, which gives the right polynomial and produces the right plot, unless you really need to centre and scale the data:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The use of `polyfit` is correct but you forget to include [`S`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html#bue6sxq-1-S) and [`mu`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html#bue6sxq-1-mu) when you plot the polynomial.

There are two options to fix your code:

**Option 1**

change

```
[p, ~, ~] = polyfit(vel, dp, 2);
plot(vel,polyval(p,vel));
```

to be

```
[p, S, mu] = polyfit(vel, dp, 2);
plot(vel,polyval(p,vel,S,mu));
```

**Option2**

Don't specify `S` and `mu`. Change

```
[p, ~, ~] = polyfit(vel, dp, 2);
```

to be

```
p = polyfit(vel, dp, 2);
```

**Output**

[image]